# How To Loop Through Pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have this df

[image: Covid-19 Italy]

and I want to create a loop that is capable to get specified value:

- the sum of people (between M and F) vaccinated,
- sum of first and sum of second dose
- selected for name area

So with conditional string appears like this:

```
br = vaccini.loc[(vaccini['fornitore'] == 'Pfizer/BioNTech') & 
             (vaccini['fascia_anagrafica'] == '20-29') & 
             (vaccini['nome_area'] == 'Abruzzo')].sum()
```

[image: result of conditional]

But I want to create a loop for more computational efficiency like:

for x in df
if **fornitore** is (same word)
if **fascia_anagrafica** is (same word)
if **nome_area** is (same word)
print(x)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a groupby.

```
cols = [s for s in vaccini.columns if s.startswith('sesso') or s.endswith('dose')]
vaccini.groupby(['fornitore', 'fascia_anagrafica', 'nome_area'])[cols].sum()
```

This would sum the provided columns within each group. If you want a specific sum, just query the resulting multi-index for the applicable row with the manufacturer, age, and location that's applicable.

Generally, with Pandas, you want to avoid doing loops if possible. There is usually some way to get around doing a loop if you look in the library, so there's a substantial element of research with Pandas (unless what you're looking for is pretty nonstandard).